# How to share .sock file between nginx docker and uwsgi docker?

Tags: python, nginx, docker, docker-compose, uwsgi

I'm using docker-compose and now have two docker containers - one is a nginx webserver, whereas the other one is ubuntu with Python uwsgi and Flask.

As I know, the best way to connect nginx and uWSGI is done by sharing a *.sock file between them and pass the requests into the file (And that what I do in older projects where I did not use dockers).

I'm wondering how can I share the sock file between the dockers in order to enable the communication between them?

And at all.. I'm wondering if this scenario of two containers - one for nginx and one for the Flask framework and uWSGI - is best practice and right to do.

Thanks

Comment: Just use tcp for uwsgi and link the containers. Socket sharing is possible, but not supported on OSX. Also, yes, having uwsgi and nginx is separate containers is best practice.

Comment: @[jordanm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032785/jordanm) Holly shit! You are right! I had tried 2 hours to share .sock file between OSX and docker(Nginx)! It works on Ubuntu with 666, i just tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to share the sock file with different docker container.

The simple solution is share the socket port between dockers.

In the uwsgi file need to add `socket=:3000`.

```
[uwsgi]

master=true
chdir=.
module=flaskapp

harakiri=60

callable=app
thunder-lock=true
socket=:3000
workers=12
threads=4
chmod-socket=666
vacuum=true
die-on-term=true
pidfile=uwsgi.pid

max-requests=5000

post-buffering=65536
post-buffering-bufsize=524288
```

the define the nginx conf. the `uwsgi_pass` section `flask:3000` means  (docker server name):(docker expose port).

```
server {
    listen 80;

    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @slack;
    }

    location @slack {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:3000;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 60s;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 60s;
        uwsgi_connect_timeout 60s;
    }
}
```

In docker-compose file:

```
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-Nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - flask

flask:
    tty: true
    container_name: flask
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "3000"

    command: uwsgi --ini ./uwsgi.ini
```

So just let the docker run one process for each docker container.

Comment: if `uwsgi` on host, what `uwsgi_pass` should be? host's IP? I had tired that, show some "Connection refused" error. thx!